# Xcode header inclusion conflict

Tags: xcode

In my project I have this header:

```
src/thread/Semaphore.h
```

In my settings, I have src as an include folder (but not directly src/thread). Nevertheless, when I try:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
```

To include the file in /usr/include/semaphore.h, Xcode keep including src/thread/Semaphore.h instead. The problem go away when I remove the file from the project (I didn't move to trash, just remove the reference, so I still can include with #include "thread/Semaphore.h"), but that seems an ugly workaround.

How can I prevent Xcode from adding include dirs recursively?